# Uploading List of Multipart files and other details in SpringBoot with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, multipart, spring-resttemplate

I'm working on a chain of microservice in Java where **A microservice** calls **B** and **B** in turn calls **C(some external service)**.
I need to call a method of **C** which accepts Multipart File and upload it to a location.

Now in **A microservice**, I can have multiple files along with some tags. Each file can have their own tags.
**A microservice** just redirects the request to **B microservice** and nothing else.

Below is how I made my `AController.java`, `AService.java` and `ARequest.java` classes.

> **AController.java**

```
@PostMapping(value="/document/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> uploadDocuments(@RequestParam(required = true) Integer clientId,  @ModelAttribute("files") List<ARequest> aRequestList) throws IOException {
        return aService.uploadDocuments(clientId, aRequestList);
    }
```

> **AService.java**

```
    public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> uploadDocuments(Integer clientId, List<ARequest> aRequestList)
            throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
        HttpEntity<ARequest> requestPayload = new HttpEntity<ARequest>(aRequestList, headers);
        ResponseEntity<List<A>> responseEResponsentity = restTemplate.exchange("SomeUrl", HttpMethod.POST,
                requestPayload, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseEntity<List<Response>>>());
    }
```

> **ARequest.java**

```
public class ARequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9156893005763135311L;
    private String documentId;
    private String tag;
    private String displayName;
    private String description;
    private MultipartFile fileContent;
}
```

My **B Microservice** has same controller method as **AController**. BService will save some data in DB which is coming in from the BRequest object and Cresponse object and return list of saved DB values for a given clientId.

Here is my Code for -

> **BController.java**

```
@PostMapping(value="/document/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> uploadDocuments(@RequestParam(required = true) Integer clientId,  @ModelAttribute("files") List<BRequest> bRequestList) throws IOException {
        return bService.uploadDocuments(clientId, bRequestList);
    }
```

BService.java

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> uploadDocuments(Integer clientId, List<BRequest> bRequestList)
        throws IOException {
    for (BRequest request : bRequestList) {
        // Call C service with request.getFileContent() and get response back
        // Save in DB (clientID, tag, displayName, description, documentId(coming from response of C)
    }
    return Response;
}
```

Response is a JPA Entity in B Microservice and is just a DTO in A microservice.

1.Can someone guide me if my approach is correct?
2. How can i test it using postman
3. If i change tweak code to get input as single Request instead of file to test it from postman, i'm getting below error when i call B Microservice from A.

```
No HttpMessageConverter for java.util.ArrayList and content type "multipart/form-data"
```

If i change some other thing, i get `400 Bad Request`

Now i'm so confused that i cant think in any direction. Please help me